# set aspxgridview settings text title from client side (jquery or javascript)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, devexpress

hi I am having an aspxgridview, 
i want to set aspxgridview  title from client side using either jquery or javascript

I tried the following code but does not worked

```
document.getElementById('gvAllRequests').setAttribute('Title', 'ejMC Dashboard( Archieved)');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if you can set the title text directly from javascript.

What you can do however is change the TitlePanel template to include a label which you can then change the text for.

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="gridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ClientInstanceName="gridView">
    <Settings ShowTitlePanel="True" />
    <SettingsText Title="Jobs" />
    <Templates>
        <TitlePanel>
            <dx:ASPxLabel runat="server" ClientInstanceName="gridViewTitle"/>
        </TitlePanel>
    </Templates>        
</dx:ASPxGridView>
    <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="ASPxTextBox1" runat="server" Width="170px" ClientInstanceName="tb" Text="TEST"></dx:ASPxTextBox>
    <dx:ASPxButton ID="ASPxButton1" runat="server" Text="Set text" AutoPostBack="False">
    <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e) {
gridViewTitle.SetText(tb.GetText());}" />
    </dx:ASPxButton>
```

This is a basic empty ASPxGridView template and as you can see the title is now an ASPxLabel which you can then change the text on the client side using the SetText method. Hope this helps